# Displaying permissions with spotify-web-api-node

Tags: node.js, spotify

I'm using spotify-web-api-node to authorize a user so I can create and modify a users playlist.
 The app works as it should. Where by the user can be directed to the spotify accounts page,be authorized, and then be redirected to my app.
 **But when on the Spotify authorize page it doesn't display the permissions(scope) sought by the application**. I'm guessing it should look like the image displayed [HERE](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/using-scopes/) on the Spotify website. Im not too sure if its a case that my code isn't complete or there might be an issue with the Spotify authorize page when using spotify-web-api-node.

### Edit

### app.js

```
 var SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');
 var http = require('http'),
 fs = require('fs'),
 index = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html');

 // Send index.html to all requests
 var app = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
 res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
 res.end(index);
 });

var scopes = ['playlist-modify-public', 'playlist-modify-private'],
redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000',
clientId = '',
clientSecret = '',
state = 'some-state-of-my-choice';

// Setting credentials can be done in the wrapper's constructor.
var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
redirectUri : redirectUri,
clientId : clientId,
clientSecret : clientSecret
});

// Create the authorization URL
var authorizeURL = spotifyApi.createAuthorizeURL(scopes, state);
console.log(authorizeURL);


// Socket.io server listens to our app
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){
io.sockets.emit('url',{value:authorizeURL});

//once code is extracted from client-side get tokens
socket.on('code', function(data){
  var code = data.x;

   // get tokens
  spotifyApi.authorizationCodeGrant(code)
    .then(function(data) {

    console.log('The token expires in ' + data['expires_in']);
    console.log('The access token is ' + data['access_token']);
    console.log('The refresh token is ' + data['refresh_token']);
    console.log(code);
    }, function(err) {
        console.log('Something went wrong with getting Auth tokens !', err);
      });
     });
   });app.listen(3000);
```

### html

```
<body>
  <a><button>Authorize</button></a>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src='//localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

   <script>
   function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

      $( document ).ready(function() {
        var socket = io.connect('//localhost:3000');
        var code = getParameterByName('code');
            socket.emit('code', { x: code});
            socket.on('url', function(data) {
             $('a').attr('href',data.value);
            });
      });
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Could you please include the method call you're making to create the Authorize URL? I'm assuming you're using the createAuthorizeURL method.

Comment: @michaelt. Correct, Im using the createAuthorizeURL. It's as follows 'var authorizeURL = spotifyApi.createAuthorizeURL(scopes);'. Where scopes is an array of permissions. Also the Authorize url contains the scope varaible, in this case I have is as 'playlist-modify-private'.

Answer (score 0):

There's [a test](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node/blob/master/test/spotify-web-api.js) that checks that the AuthorizeURL includes scopes. Make sure that the scopes you're sending in  is in an array. Your code should look something like this (obviously with scopes, redirectUri, clientId, and state changed to your application's values)

```
var scopes = ['user-read-private', 'user-read-email'],
redirectUri = 'https://example.com/callback',
clientId = '5fe01282e44241328a84e7c5cc169165',
state = 'some-state-of-my-choice';

var api = new SpotifyWebApi({
    clientId : clientId,
    redirectUri : redirectUri
});

var authorizeURL = api.createAuthorizeURL(scopes, state);
console.log(authorizeURL); // "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=5fe01282e44241328a84e7c5cc169165&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://example.com/callback&scope=user-read-private%20user-read-email&state=some-state-of-my-choice"
```

Hope this helps! If not, please include your code in your question.

Comment: Iv update my question with the code. So the authorizeURL is the same as the one you've commented in the code above. It's when the user is on the log in page of spotify it says "Connect MyApp to your Spotify account." and nothing about the permissions the app wants to use. Again, I'm not too sure if it should. But when I ran the code from this example [link](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/tutorial/) the user is told what permissions are being sought when on the spotify login page.

Comment: That's very interesting. Could you please paste the URL that's being generated by createAuthorizeURL? (https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/?client_id= ...)

Comment: It's: `https://accounts.spotify.com/ie/authorize?client_id=d40343da0b6249ed96f1c6628944014d&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2Flocalhost:3000&scope=playlist-modify-public%20playlist-modify-private&state=some-state-of-my-choice`